Link to Add item into a lookup list
Is the following possible in SharePoint Online.
I have a list A. One of the columns within list A is a lookup type column to list B.
What I would like to do is have an option to add a new item to list B from within list A.
I was thinking of adding a link (URL) to List A, for example 'Add new item', which would take the user to the Add new item (to List B) dialogue box - but I am not sure if this is possible. Any suggestions?
The main aim here is to make navigation as simple as possible for the end user. Normally they would open List B in a new window to add a new item to that list, which they would then have to select in List A in the Lookup column. I just want to make that navigation to List B as simple as possible.

Yes, it is possible to add a new item to List B from within List A in SharePoint Online. One way to achieve this is by using Power Apps. You can create a custom form in Power Apps that allows the user to add a new item to List B, and then embed this form in List A. When the user clicks on the "Add new item" link in List A, the Power Apps form will open, allowing them to add a new item to List B. Another way to achieve this is by using SharePoint Designer to create a custom form for List A that includes a button to add a new item to List B.
References:
How to link lists from Microsoft Lists using a lookup column in Power Apps

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.
